# M365 SharePoint Excel Macros

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

Hi I saw a couple of posts about not running macros in M365 but wondered if anyone could suggest a solution to our specific problem:

We have multiple users who need to co-author a workbook in a M365 SharePoint document library. This same workbook needs to run macros occasionally. One option we have looked at is download the workbook to the client application but when you try to edit it makes you save a different copy which is leading to mistakes administratively. Also I understand that co-authoring needs to be done in the browser. Is there some better way where we can facilitate the 2 main requirements: Co-authoring and macros in one workbook?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could use [Microsoft 365 client application](https://www.office.com/?auth=2).

When storing files in the SharePoint or OneDrive for business, open them in the Microsoft 365 client application and log in with Microsoft 365 account, you could meet the needs of authoring and macros.